# Missing lines from table

Tags: tables

See attached figure - the upperright corner has a portion of the table borders cut off. [image]

How do I amend the code pasted below?

```
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{table*}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Example}
\label{tab:example} 
\begin{tabular}{|M{0.1\linewidth} M{0.15\linewidth} M{0.2\linewidth} M{0.25\linewidth} M{0.2\linewidth}|}
\hline  \\
A & B & C & D & E \\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ \hline   
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline 

\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: don't use `\\ ` after `\hline`

Comment: nor before (take a look to the `booktabs` package to understand why).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is solved by comments.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is solved by comments, but you may find the following suggestions (mostly of topic) useful ...

By use of `tabularray` package code for your table can be:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\caption{Example with horizontal lines in table body}
\label{tab:example-1}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vline{1,Z}={solid},
             colspec = { *{2}{X[0.15, c,m]} X[0.2, c,m] X[0.25, c,m]   X[0.2, c,m] },žđ
             rowsep=5pt
             }
A & B & C & D & E   \\  
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5   \\  
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10  \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table*}

    \begin{table*}[ht]
\caption{Example with horizontal lines in table body}
\label{tab:example-2}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = { *{2}{X[0.15, c,m]} X[0.2, c,m] X[0.25, c,m]   X[0.2, c,m] },žđ
             rowsep=5pt
             }
    \toprule
A & B & C & D & E   \\
    \midrule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5   \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]